# View Task Error - URL No Longer Exists

Tags: tasks, url

I have just noticed now that if I try to view any of the existing Task on salesforce and I click on a particular Task record, it displays the information for around 2 seconds then it redirect me on the following page:

> URL No Longer Exists

All the task information appears to be normal if I view it in a report. Does anybody know what might cause this issue?

Note: Events work perfectly

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar when you are redirected? Could be some custom script you have loading on the form?

Comment: The url I'm redirected to is something like: https://<instance>.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=06......00021sgv&ic=1&linkToken=Vm................R0po

Comment: I'm going to guess that the Task page is either a) a detail page with an embedded VF page that has some error in the embedded page/controller or b) a custom Task VF page that has some other issue (Javascript error)